# Revolution Slider images disappear

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I have a website http://fotoclasses.com and I just changed its server. On new server, revolution slider of wordpress is not working correctly. On homepage, you will see that image disappear instantly. I have searched as well as tried to create new slides etc but problem is still there in new ones as well.

Here is the setting of one slide [image]

Any idea what is causing this issue?

Thanks
Hamza

Comment: If I had to guess, the server configs are not 1:1 and there is some missing PHP module/extension.

Answer (score 0):

I look at your website and when i open your website the slider image is shown but after the content on you slider is displayed then the back image is gone. Please refer http://prntscr.com/8hztq9. So may be issue is on your setting of sliding slide image and content rotation.